# A better way to write dplyr pipes? (without using dollar sign)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Quite often when using the tidyverse to manipulate data, I come up with a situation like the one below. Can someone explain why option 3 works, but 1 and 2 doesn't? Is there a better way than option 3 -- i.e "clean" looking code that doesn't use the dollar sign? I thought one idea with dplyr was to get away from using the dollar sign?

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Want this to work (doesn't)
mtcars %>%
  str_replace(mpg, ",", ".")

# 2. Second best (doesn't work)
mtcars %>%
  select(mpg) %>% 
  str_replace(",", ".")

# 3. This works, but don't like the use of $
mtcars$mpg %>% 
  str_replace(",", ".")

# 4. It looks even uglier when saving as an object:

mtcars$mpg <- mtcars$mpg %>% 
  str_replace(",", ".")
```

Comment: `mutate(mpg=str_replace(mpg, ",", "."))` ?

Comment: Or `mtcars %>% use_series(mpg) %>% ...`

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! So you use the str_replace *inside* mutate. Thanks!

Comment: Why the hate for the `$`? It's part of base R and makes it clear what you are doing. Better still don't use the pipe: `mtcars$mpg <- str_replace(mtcars$mpg, ",", ".")`. Or if you want to use it, at least make it work for you: `library(magrittr); mtcars$mpg %<>% str_replace(",", ".")`

Comment: @dash see jay.sf comment. No hate for $ from me. But if you are not using base r but dplyr to wrangle date, $ is not so great imho.

Comment: Maybe `with(mtcars, str_replace(mpg, ",", "."))`

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use pipe, you can use `%$%` which is a part of `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %$% 
  str_replace(mpg, ",", ".")
```